# What is this syntax supposed to do?

Tags: php, oop

I am managing a website with a custom framework, developed by some programmers who are no longer working in out company. In some parts of the code I saw this:

```
$class = 'PagesControl';
$obj = clone new $class();
```

What is this thing supposed to do? Why would you clone an object created like that?

Comment: Object Cloning: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe they have some strange setup in the [`__clone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) method that need to be called just after instatiation but it would be pretty pointless. If the class `PagesControl` has no `__clone()` method, just take off the `clone`, otherwise put the code that is present in the `__clone()` method inside the `__construct()`

Answer (score 12):

No, it is meaningless.

It should be:

```
$class = 'PagesControl';
$obj = new $class();
```

And if $class is fixed, then it should be `$obj = new PagesControl();`